# Syncing Windows Phone 7 and Computer

Tags: window, data-transfer, windows-phone

For unknown reasons, my phone will not sync via Zune. I have asked on Microsoft Answers and the response is slow and useless!

All software (phone and Zune) are up to date.

I plug my phone into my PC (W7) and it detects. Zune launches. I click on Phone - Videos. I can see all the videos. I drag them to the little computer icon (which copies from phone to computer). During the transfer, a % increments as it copies. On my copy, it never gets above 2%. Typically, it will go similar to 0%, 1%, 0%, 1%, 0%, 1%, 2%, 0% etc. I don't think I've seen it past 4%.

Under settings, Sync Options videos is selected to Manual.

Under sync groups, there is only 1 file which appears under video (the only file which has synced to my PC - about 6 months ago).

I have re-installed the software and even applied the hotfix.

I have 'forgotten my phone' and reset it up.

The destination folder on my PC is the My Video folder and I've ensured permissions are set to everyone (full rights).

I have also noticed, under the phone tab, if I click on Pictures it shows how many MB and how many are free. It says 38.39MB (Free 364.41MB).

Under videos, despite being multiple videos, it says Videos 0.00MB (out of 364.41mb). The same is also true for music.

FYI since it's last successful sync, I've got a new PC.

Kaspersky (AVP) is disabled.

I'm looking for a resolution OR a work around. Windows does not detect the phone as an external device, my searches on Google produce 0 results for such software (to bypass Zune). It appears I'm stuck with Zune but as it's not working, I feel I'm running out of options.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have 'forgotten my phone' and reset it up.
>
> ...
>
> FYI since it's last successful sync, I've got a new PC.

I'm assuming you just unpaired the phone with Zune. What I would suggest you to do is a full reset of your phone, also configure Windows using `msconfig` such that it only launches the necessary stuff to ensure you run just a plain unpaired Windows Phone 7 and a plain unpaired  Zune on a plain Windows. This should make pairing and syncing a breeze...

If pairing again doesn't work, I would be assuming it to be Windows as your phone is just an image and I wouldn't think that image would differ that much. Hence, in this case I would suggest you to either find another computer to test syncing from or to set up a testing Windows. If you know how a virtual machines works, like Virtualbox, you should know that you can forward USB to the virtual machine and run Zune on a Windows XP VM. If running it from another computer or a VM works, then there is something up with your Windows installation, if it does not it is indeed your phone.

If it's your Windows, I am afraid the best approach is to just reinstall or do some more troubleshooting. If it is your Windows Phone I guess you will have to take it back such that they can reinsntall Windows Phone 7 to it. Good luck whatever the results of testing this might be!

> I'm looking for a resolution OR a work around. Windows does not detect the phone as an external device, my searches on Google produce 0 results for such software (to bypass Zune). It appears I'm stuck with Zune but as it's not working, I feel I'm running out of options.

Since it is proprietary, the only way to access your Windows Phone is through Zune.

Comment: Tom, thank you. It was a work around, but I was happy to get the pictures and video off - I tried it on my W7 netbook and it's done what it should have done. I will try to diagnose the issue with my main PC (and if I find a result I will post another answer or make an edit). Thank you for the time, and for such a clear answer.